# For loop not give proper output by defining as below in smarty framework

Tags: smarty

Anybody have an idea how to use for loop in smarty template? I want to define condition as below.

```
<?php
        $quer = "select * from users";
        $res1 = $conn->query($quer);
        $count = $res1->num_rows;

        $a = $count/10;
        $a = ceil($a);
            echo "<br/>"; echo "<br/>";
```

I want to convert below for loop in a smarty for loop how it is possible?

```
        for($b=1; $b<=$a ; $b++){ 
                ?><a href="home.php?page=<?php echo $b;?>" style="text-decoration:none;"><?php echo $b." ";?></a><?php
            }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is simple (put it in your template file):

```
{for $b=1 to $end}
    <a href="home.php?page={$b}" style="text-decoration:none;">{$b} </a>
{/for}
```

Read more about smarty loops in documentation: [for](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.for.tpl), [foreach](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl).